# wordpress multisite installation with existing live domains

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk, multisite

OK, this may be silly, but, I haven't found an answer yet. I have a client that wants to take 14 existing live domains and convert them to WordPress. Sounds like WP multisite would be perfect. They all will have the same look and feel and pages for the most part.

But, my question, where do I install it? I don't want to use any of the existing domains as they are live. Do I just make up a master domain, like example.com, and use Plesk's IP default domain to preview?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

if your sites data is related to each other you can use one wordpress installation on example.com and develop it to support all.

else you can convert each site to wordpress and place each one in a separate directory
for example : example.com/site1 , example.com/site2 ...

then do permanent redirect for each one to it's directory like bellow:

site1.com permanent redirect to example.com/site1

site2.com permanent redirect to example.com/site2

.

.

Comment: So, I should make up a fake domain and use that, like example.com? That is actually my question. Thanks so much.

Comment: you need to register another domain, then connect it to a host that can support all 14 websites. move all your websites to new host as i mentioned above. you do not need any of old hosts any more. you just need your domains. after that do permanent redirects and you'r good to go.
notice that rank of all your old domains will be awarded to your new domain

Comment: Hmmm, OK I guess, not moving server, It's a VPS with other domains and so forth. So, register a dummy domain. Huh, OK. Seems like there should be a better option. But, one never knows. All the answers I get are for starting from scratch more or less.